# There is a problem when calling another function from a function in the same class

Tags: python, python-3.x, methods, call

I use python3.
It is not recognized when another function is called from a function in the class.
here my code and error message

These codes erase all the complex stuff, and only the ones that matter. I just want to call get_contents() in the main function. And get_contents() should call get_response().

```
class TClass:
    def get_response():
        return 'response'

    def get_contents():
        content = get_response()
        return content

    if __name__   == "__main__":
        contents = get_contents()
        print (contents)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mul/Project/mybase.py", line 2, in <module>
    class TClass:
  File "/Users/mul/Project/mybase.py", line 11, in TClass
    contents = get_contents()
  File "/Users/mul/Project/mybase.py", line 7, in get_contents
    content = get_response()
NameError: name 'get_response' is not defined
```

help me. please

"""
I am studying Python by looking at the documents. I didn't know that the main function had to be outside the function.
Thanks to everyone who helped, even though it was too easy.
"""

Comment: What are you trying to do with ```if __name__   == "__main__":
        contents = get_contents()
        print (contents)```. Whats the expected output?

Comment: These codes erase all the complex stuff, and only the ones that matter.
I just want to call get_contents() in the main function. And get_contents() should call get_response().

Comment: You're trying to call the class method without instantiation?

Comment: Thank you for your help and attention. Thanks to that, it worked out well.

Answer (score 3):

1. The main should be out of the class.
2. The actions inside of the class probably receive self as a parameter; `get_response` could handle without it, and could be static, and if so then `get_contents` probably should be static too. If so, you should add a decorator before it: `@staticmethod`.

I guess that your code should be:

```
class TClass:
    def get_response(self):
        return 'response'

    def get_contents(self):
        content = self.get_response()
        return content

if __name__   == "__main__":
    object_t = TClass()
    contents = object_t.get_contents()
    print (contents)
```

Comment: I solved it easily thanks to you. 
I am very clumsy because I am new to python. I hope for a lot of help in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you're trying to achieve. But here is my similar approach.
If you were to make methods static you can avoid instantiation.

```
class TClass:
    @staticmethod
    def get_response():
        return 'response'
    
    @staticmethod
    def get_contents():
        content = TClass.get_response()
        return content

if __name__   == "__main__":
    contents = TClass.get_contents()
    print (contents)
```

Comment: Thank you. But I don't want a staticmethod. I just didn't know that the main function had to be outside the function.